Caddy might not support NoIp
I want to run my website (just for fun) on my computer that runs Windows 11. I decide to use nextjs. I will use docker and run the website and noip to my map between my ip and the domain name. I want to use Caddy as server to generate ssl on the fly.
This is my Dockerfile:


# Use a lightweight Node.js image as the base
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install (or yarn install)

# Copy the rest of the project files (excluding node_modules)
COPY . .

# Create a non-root user for the application process
RUN adduser --disabled-password --shell /bin/bash appuser

# Switch to the non-root user for the application process
USER appuser

# Use a multi-stage build to create a smaller production image
FROM caddy:latest AS final

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Expose port 3000 for the Next.js application
EXPOSE 3000

# Copy the Caddyfile to the appropriate location
COPY Caddyfile /etc/caddy/Caddyfile

# Start the Next.js development server in production mode using Caddy
CMD ["caddy", "run", "--config", "/etc/caddy/Caddyfile"]



and this is my docker-compose.yml


version: "3.9"  # Specify the Docker Compose version

services:
  nextjs-app:
build: .
ports:
  - "8080:3000"  # Map container port 3000 to host port 8080
volumes:
  - ./:/app:rw  # Mount the project directory as a volume for live updates
environment:
  - VIRTUAL_HOST=my-domain.com  # Set the virtual host for Caddy

  caddy:
image: caddy:latest
restart: always
ports:
  - "8081:80"
  - "443:443"
volumes:
  - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
  - caddy_data:/data
  - caddy_config:/config

volumes:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:



I also create the new file Caddyfile at the same level with docker-compose.yml


`my-domain.com {
reverse_proxy nextjs-app:8080
tls {
    dns noip "abc" "xyz" (abc and xyz are the user name and password from created DDNS key)
}
}`





When I run docker, I got this error 

2024-04-07 21:30:36 Error: adapting config using caddyfile: parsing caddyfile tokens for 'tls': getting module named 'dns.providers.noip': module not registered: dns.providers.noip, at /etc/caddy/Caddyfile:4
2024-04-07 21:31:37 {"level":"info","ts":1712518297.3449285,"msg":"using provided configuration","config_file":"/etc/caddy/Caddyfile","config_adapter":"caddyfile"}
2024-04-07 21:31:37 Error: adapting config using caddyfile: parsing caddyfile tokens for 'tls': getting module named 'dns.providers.noip': module not registered: dns.providers.noip, at /etc/caddy/Caddyfile:4



I think noip is not supported by Caddy. Anyone experienced this issue?
I tried to not use Chat GPT because I feel bored and wanna discuss with real people :(
